# grunt karma testing on vagrant when host changes sources grunt/karma doesn't detect it

Tags: linux, gruntjs, vagrant, virtualbox, karma-runner

This took me ages to find out but can't seem to find a solution for this one. Using vagrant I run a Fedora 20 guest that runs grunt/karma. The sources I edit on my host but when I save grunt isn't detecting the change so no tests are being done.

Figured it was a configuration problem so tried many combinations of things here without success. Finally I opened a second ssh to the guest `vagrang ssh` and changed the file in the other ssh terminal `echo " " >> app/js/app.js` and see that now grunt/karma detects the change and runs the tests again.

Since it has no x windows or anything I'm running the tests with PhantomJS. Another problem was that I had to set `EnableSendfile off` in the httpd.conf to prevent Apache to send garbage when serving textfiles from the share (that's my project in host and web root in guest). My guess is there may be another setting that needs being done to node so it detects the changes made by the host to the files on the share. It's using virtualBox share.

Has anyone experienced this before and is there a solution for this? Seems that host machine changing files on the share doesn't trigger some event that grunt/karma is listening for to indicate the file has changed.

**[update]**

Tried NFS and rsync share but NFS didn't work at all and rsync seems to just sync on startup.

**[update]**

As a temporary solution I have to manually tell the file is updated in the ssh terminal:

```
#start grunt and give me back command:
grunt &
#when I update a file tell grunt it's updated
touch -d "now" test/unit/loginSpec.js
```

Funny that if I update `app/js/login.js` and tell grunt the `test/unit/loginSpec.js` is updated it will run the tests again but with the old login.js even though it has changed `cat app/js/login.js` shows the changes. If not for this the solution would be set focus to right window and 2 keystroke (arrow up and enter)

Comment: Sounds like a network configuration problem not a coding problem... or are you compiling your own fork of grunt?

Comment: @BenVoigt It is definitely a problem with how the share is implemented. Though if the host changes files the file changes can be seen on the guest with the correct last modified dates. It's just that the grunt watch (node) doesn't detect the file as being changed.

Comment: Are you writing/modifying the code that implements the share?

Comment: @BenVoigt The guest hosts the symfony part of the project as well as nodejs, grunt and tools for testing the angularjs part. The host is used to edit the code as it has the IDE (netbeans). The share is so I am able to modify code on the host and have it immediately run on the guest (standard vagrant setup).

Comment: You didn't answer my question... it sounds like you have a configuration issue with networking, which is (1) not your code and (2) not a developer tool, therefore off-topic on StackOverflow.  For networking, remote mounts, and virtual machine hosting issues, you might try SuperUser and ServerFault.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for your reply. I don't agree with you because vagrant is a developer tool and the whole point of the share is so you can run multiple server configurations for clients/projects on one dev machine: http://www.vagrantup.com/ For this to work settings are needed for Apache and I suspect for nodejs to have grunt watches work. The Apache part is documented and mentioned but can't find the grunt watches part so asking it here.

Comment: Just like "I plan to install Visual Studio on this box" is not justification for asking arbitrary Windows questions here, neither is "I'm running vagrant on this box" justification for asking Linux configuration questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This derives from a known bug in the synchronization of vboxsf (Virtualbox “sharded folder” filesystem) and the solution to this issue only can be implemented by the Virtualbox team. People have had similar problems with Gulp, Guard or Meteor.js (to name a few).

There are some workarounds that you could use…

### Auto-rsync

Vagrant 1.5 has an auto-synchronization utility (**[rsync-auto](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-rsync.html)**) that watches specified folders, and automatically syncs changes as you make them in real-time. It uses system-specific APIs to detect file changes, rather than polling the file system…

So you just should define your shares in the vagrant file. I.e:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
```

and open an additional terminal session running:

```
$ vagrant rsync-auto
```

However, this alone is not the most *efficient* option. Here you can find a **[gruntfile](https://gist.github.com/arnaudbreton/9517344)** and a [**vagrant plugin**](https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-gatling-rsync) that will help you make your rsync run faster and smoother...

Hope it helps!